# How do I stop getting charged for AWS Relational Database Service?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I keep getting charged for AWS RDS backup storage, but I have no backups. How can I stop this?

Here are my charges a few days ago:

[image]

Here they are now:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYDz1.png]

Here are my backups:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBXHA.png]

Here are my snapshots:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfsJH.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbt8f.png]

[enter image description here][5]

Comment: What do you mean by "keep getting charged"? Is this 2c amount increasing? Based on the bill, you had an Amazon RDS database running at some stage during the month, so it might have charged for that time period.

Comment: Hey, it might be. I have contacted support and will be watching to see if the price changes tomorrow. @JohnRotenstein

Comment: By "keep getting charged", I mean my bill keeps increasing daily even if I don't have any services running on AWS. @JohnRotenstein

Comment: Could you possibly edit your question to show an updated version of the bill, as well as the above one, so we can see what is changing?

Comment: I have updated the bill. The prices have not changed. @JohnRotenstein

Comment: So, everything good now?

Comment: Hey, everything is good now. I still contacted support and will be watching it for a few days just to be 100%. @JohnRotenstein

Answer (score 1):

This will also include anything under the snapshots tab.

The tab in your second picture is for automated backups, the snapshots tab will contain manual snapshots that were taken such as when you delete an RDS instance.

Both are considered to be backups in the billing you are charged each month.

Comment: Hey, I have no snapshots though, and this is the second time I was charged for it in the last two days. I have added screenshots.

Comment: Have you got RDS instances in multiple regions?

Comment: Is there anyway to stop being charged for backups? @ChrisWilliams

Comment: No only in one region.

Comment: Hmm, ok have you got cost explorer enabled?

Comment: No, I don't have it enabled. I won't enable it because I read that once you enable it you can disable it and you incur 0.01$ charge.

Comment: OK, how are you seeing the cost increase for a second day? :)

Comment: Yeah, it was $16.35 yesterday and went up to $16.36 today.

Comment: OK and you removed the backups more than 2 days ago?

Comment: The backup storage doubled in size and I don't know how. http://prntscr.com/t7fqo4

Comment: Yeah I removed it two days ago.

Comment: Remember that these bills are not always 100% accurate (thats why people tend to use cost explorer to see closer to what they'll be charged). I would suggest you contact AWS support, if theres no backups there but you're being charged its a technical support issue.

Comment: Hey, I wen't to another region and I noticed, that it had no parameter groups http://prntscr.com/t7fsgy. But in my region I have default parameter groups http://prntscr.com/t7fsy4, why is that?

Comment: Hey, I wen't to another region and I noticed, that it had no parameter groups http://prntscr.com/t7fsgy. But in my region I have default parameter groups http://prntscr.com/t7fsy4, why is that?

Comment: These rules only get created once you make an RDS instance in that region.

Comment: It doesn't let me delete the default parameter groups http://prntscr.com/t7fto8.

Comment: Have you got an RDS instance running using that parameter group?